# Setting state form a data fetch, is this an Anti Pattern?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to work out how to do an API call then get a timestamp for a specific location then start a clock for that location? I've got it working but I'm just wondering if this is correct? I'm going to stick this in a flux architecture eventually. I'm setting state from props, anti pattern? I only want to make one initial request then manipulate the interval, so I figured it would be best to use state.

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sc42yt65/)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      time: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const URL = 'http://api.timezonedb.com/?lat=37.773972&lng=-122.431297&format=json&&key=XXXXXXXXXXX';
    const _this = this;
    fetch(URL)
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      }).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        _this.setState({
          time: data.timestamp
        });
      }).catch(function() {
       reject(err);
      });
      this.interval = setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000);
  }
  tick() {
    this.setState({
      time: this.state.time + 1
    });
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
  render() {
     return (
        <div>
            <p>Time on West Coast:</p> {moment.unix(this.state.time).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')}
        </div>

     );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely not an anti-pattern. Check out [this example](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/examples%2Fflux-chat%2Fjs%2Fcomponents%2FMessageSection.react.js#L41-L45) on the Flux Github repository where a component registers for data updates (like your `setInterval`) in its `componentDidMount` method.

```
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this._scrollToBottom();
    MessageStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
    ThreadStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
  },
```

Then, just like you, it unregisters in `componentWillUnmount`.

```
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    MessageStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
    ThreadStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
  },
```

The only difference is in how it gets its data initially, in its "constructor"

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return getStateFromStores();
  },
```

It gets its state from the store. You are collecting data from an api in `componentDidMount`. This is a common thing to do before stores get involved. Once you have a store, all data access should go through it. This allows multiple components to get the same data without multiple requests being made. It also encapsulates the collection methods, which helps with testability.

You say you are setting state from props, but I don't see this in your code.

Comment: ok think i worked it out                            componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) { 
    this.setState({
      time: nextProps.data.timestamp
    });
  }